# get transactionId from DoExpressCheckoutPayment reply

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

im having trouble getting the transaction id plus other info from the reply from doexpresscheckoutpayment, ive spent a few nights reading but im either not understanding whats happening or im getting something wrong somehwere

here some code

```
    function ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )
{

    //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
    $token              = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
    $paymentType        = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
    $currencyCodeType   = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
    $payerID            = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);

    $serverName         = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    $nvpstr  = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName; 

     /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        */
    $resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);

    /* Display the API response back to the browser.
       If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
       If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
       */
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

    return $resArray;
}
```

then

```
$resArray = ConfirmPayment($finalPaymentAmount);
$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {

    $transactionId = $resArray["TRANSACTIONID"]; // ' Unique transaction ID of the payment. Note:  If the PaymentAction of the request was Authorization or Order, this value is your AuthorizationID for use with the Authorization & Capture APIs.
    $transactionType = $resArray["TRANSACTIONTYPE"]; //' The type of transaction Possible values: l  cart l  express-checkout
    $paymentType = $resArray["PAYMENTTYPE"]; //' Indicates whether the payment is instant or delayed. Possible values: l  none l  echeck l  instant
    $orderTime = $resArray["ORDERTIME"]; //' Time/date stamp of payment
```

etc etc

the doexprescheoutpayment works as it does finalise the paypal payment, its just that $transactionID and the others are always empty and i would like to record these

can some1 point me in the right direction

thanks
craig

Comment: Inside your `if` conditional, have you tried dumping the contents of `$resArray` to ensure you're getting the results you expect? Log or email the results.

Comment: good idea, would have saved myself a lot of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PayPal's `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoExpressCheckoutPayment) operation docs:

> TRANSACTIONID is deprecated since version 63.0. Use
>   PAYMENTINFO_n_TRANSACTIONID instead.

Similarly, `PAYMENTTYPE`, `TRANSACTIONTYPE`, and `ORDERTIME` are deprecated. Check the provided link for the updated variable names in the response message.

Comment: thankyou very much, stupid mistake on my part, but thankyou for pointing me in the right direction, my code seems ok now have changed the depreciated stuff

Comment: No problem! Sometimes all it takes is a little help.